# Redefining indexing in N-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, indexing

So I have a N-dimensional array of values, let's call it A. Now, I can plot this in a contour map, with coordinate axes X and Y, using

```
plt.contourf(X,Y,A)
```

Now, I have to carry out a mapping of these points to another plane, so, basically another set of coordinates. Let the transformation be

```
X - X1
Y - X1
```

Now, each point with magnitude "I" in matrix A at (X,Y) is at (X- X1, Y - Y1). I can plot this using

```
plt.contourf(X-X1, Y-Y1,A)
```

My question is, how do I index the array A such that I obtain an array B where the indexing corresponds to X-X1 and Y-Y1 instead of X and Y so that I can plot it directly using the following

```
plt.contourf(X,Y,B)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some number, `j`, such that `X[i+j] == (X[i]-X1)`.  In other words can you get `X-X1` by just slicing `X`?  Otherwise this looks like an interpolation problem, not an indexing one.

Comment: This is a 2D array, right?  Just 2 coordinate array.  Contouring 3d doesn't fit your description.  Though the question of whether you need to interpolate or can just take a slice applies with ploting 1d `A` against ``X` as well (and may be easier to discuss).

Comment: @hpaulj, i'm not sure...I don't think so, I just have the matrix for X1, nothing else...And it isn't a 3d contouring, its merely a contour plot of a 2D array....I just have two new axes that I want to plot the matrix A against, and instead of doing X-X1 and Y-Y1, I want to be able to plot it in terms of X and Y

Comment: Isn't any index into A explicitly a value at an implicit coordinate? In other words, values in A don't contain any information for where they should be plotted besides their index position which are assigned coordinates in space by X and Y.

Comment: Yes correct, my question is, how do I change the indexing in A such that I can plot it in the same way I would with (X-X1,Y-Y1).